# MDX COUNT ON DIMENSION

Tags: count, mdx, dimensions

I have a mdx query which can give me distinct eid, region and country:

```
SELECT ([Measures].[Active Tiles Count]) ON 0,
NON EMPTY ([Employee].[Employee Id].Children,[Employee - Business Region].  [Region Code].Children,[Employee - Country].[Country Code].Children) ON 1
FROM [OLAP Pre]
WHERE ( 
{[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[1],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[4],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[3]},
{[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[APJ],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[EMEA],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[Americas]},
{[Employee Types].[Bits].&[1],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[9],
[Employee Types].[Bits].&[25],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[5],
[Employee Types].[Bits].&[13],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[29]}
,{[Date].[Date].&[2015-03-18T00:00:00]:NULL})
```

But I want **COUNT**(**DISTINCT**(employEEid)) grouped by region and country.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a DISTINCT COUNT MEASURE, It's a Predefined aggregation types

Answer (score 0):

Try making use of the `DISTINCTCOUNT` function

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[CountOfDistinctEmployes] AS
DISTINCTCOUNT([Employee].[Employee Id].Children)

SELECT {[Measures].[Active Tiles Count], Measures.[CountOfDistinctEmployes]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY ([Employee].[Employee Id].Children,[Employee - Business Region].  [Region Code].Children,[Employee - Country].[Country Code].Children) ON 1
FROM [OLAP Pre]
WHERE ( 
{[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[1],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[4],[Employee Statuses].[Status Id].&[3]},
{[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[APJ],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[EMEA],[Business Region].[Abbreviation].&[Americas]},
{[Employee Types].[Bits].&[1],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[9],
[Employee Types].[Bits].&[25],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[5],
[Employee Types].[Bits].&[13],[Employee Types].[Bits].&[29]}
,{[Date].[Date].&[2015-03-18T00:00:00]:NULL})
```